# Tool for visualizing activity in Git repo

Tags: data-visualization, git, history

Is there something for a local repository to:

1) show how frequently all the files and directories of repository are changed;

2) for a certain file: show how frequently the lines and paragraphs are changed?

Optionally with a timelapse.

Comment: On what OS should it run? And what is your budget?

Answer (score 1):

For option 1 (show frequency of file/directory changes), Gource is an open-source tool that creates visually interesting displays of git project histories, though it's geared more towards looking cool than doing analysis of the changes.  You supply it a project and it will generate an animation of the file tree, showing how often files are touched by commits.

Home page is [gource.io](http://gource.io/), and the project is also on [github](https://github.com/acaudwell/Gource).

I don't have a good suggestion for request 2 (line by line historical information), though if you're up for a coding challenge you might be able to adapt the gource source code to your needs.